# Reading datas from obd elm327 python-OBD

Tags: python, obd-ii

I would like to log datas via OBD2 with ELM327, and I am new in Python.

I can send a command and get a response. But I cannot send more queries and get the responses, only for the first command, the rest of responses are "None".

My code:

```
import obd, time


connection = obd.OBD(baudrate=38400, fast=True) # auto-connects to USB or RF port


while True:
    for i in commands_list:
        cmd1 = obd.commands.RPM       # select an OBD command (sensor)
        response1 = connection.query(cmd1) # send the command, and parse the response
        print(response1.value) # returns unit-bearing values thanks to Pint
        # connection.close()

        cmd2 = obd.commands.COOLANT_TEMP # select an OBD command (sensor)
        response2 = connection.query(cmd2) # send the command, and parse the response
        print(response2.value)
        # connection.close()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

The output is: (with stopped engine, on ignition)

```
0.0 revolutions_per_minute
None
0.0 revolutions_per_minute
None
0.0 revolutions_per_minute
None
```

The expected output:

```
0.0 revolutions_per_minute
91 degC
0.0 revolutions_per_minute
91 degC
0.0 revolutions_per_minute
91 degC
```

It is work with closing connection after getting each responses, but it is really slow... I woule like to get responses after max. 1 sec. The optimal would be at least 0.5 s.

Has anyone idea or experience with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set fast mode to false:

```
connection = obd.OBD(baudrate=38400, fast=False)
```

***Function description:***

> fast: Allows commands to be optimized before being sent to the car.
>   Python-OBD currently makes two such optimizations:
>
> Sends carriage returns to repeat the previous command. Appends a
>   response limit to the end of the command, telling the adapter to
>   return after it receives N responses (rather than waiting and
>   eventually timing out). This feature can be enabled and disabled for
>   individual commands.
>   **Disabling fast mode will guarantee that python-OBD outputs the unaltered command for every request.**

Source: [LINK](https://python-obd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Connections/#obdportstrnone-baudratenone-protocolnone-fasttrue)